# how do i scan my website to determine which version of jquery other libraries are using

Tags: jquery, ajax, pci-compliance

My site is failing a PCI scan because of a jQuery vulnerability - [CVE-2015-9251](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2015-9251) - jQuery Cross-Domain AJAX vulnerability - in jQuery versions less than 3.x.x. I have scanned all of my pages and all are using jQuery 3.3.1. Reading the description of the failed scan more closely revealed this (highlight added):

> This finding indicates that either the root domain url, sub-domain
>   url, or an **imported**/sourced version of jQuery is below jQuery version
>   3.0.

I'm sure the site uses other frameworks that may also be importing a version of jQuery. How can I determine which framework library might be including an old jQuery version?

Comment: Interesting question, I +1'd as I'm keen to see what solutions people come up with. I guess in a more "modern" world with npm, yarn and things of the like the package descriptors ought to let you view the dependency tree even transitively or let you lock versions of the packages to ensure libs are being kept up to date and audited.

Comment: The first naive suggestions that come to mind might be to look try to establish is there some common bit of code that would appear in any version of jquery. You could then have something like wget crawl your site and download all files locally (including remote scripts - providing they aren't loading extra scripts dynamically when the code executes). Once you have all of the code locally you could use standard tools like cat, grep, find etc to search files and start excluding the known ones and see what's left... not sure how feasible that is in your particular size of code base.